# Top and bottom button clicked the obj model is flipped in opengl?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, render

@Anton I stucked this flipping.

I downloaded the project from [here](https://github.com/antonholmquist/rend-ios).
I have four buttons each button set the title as right,left,bottom,top to the str variable.

In rendering the initial rotation axis is teapotNode_.rotationAxis = CC3VectorMake(0.1, 1, 0.3);

```
- (void)update:(float)dt
{

    if ([str isEqualToString:@"right"])
    {

        teapotNode_.rotationAxis = CC3VectorMake(0.1, 1, 0.3);
        angle +=2.0;
    }
    else if ([str isEqualToString:@"left"])
    {

        teapotNode_.rotationAxis = CC3VectorMake(0.1, 1, 0.3);
        angle -=2.0;
    }
    else if ([str isEqualToString:@"bottom"])
    { 

        teapotNode_.rotationAxis = CC3VectorMake(1,0,0);
        angle +=2.0;

    }
    else if ([str isEqualToString:@"top"])
    {

        teapotNode_.rotationAxis = CC3VectorMake(1,0,0);
        angle -=2.0;

    }   
    else{

        angle +=2.0;
    }    
    teapotNode_.rotationAngle = angle;

}
```

I touch the top(or)down rotation button change the axis like 
teapotNode_.rotationAxis = CC3VectorMake(1,0,0); object flipped.

I want the same axis position to rotate the object top to bottom and bottom to top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

You itself says the rotation axis value as (0.1,1,0.3) initial one. so don't change that value.

This project itself having separate function for rotation. that is `teapotNode_.rotation`

Use like this. Its working fine for me. Try this.

Globally declared:

```
float x=0.0;
float y=0.0;
float z=0.0;
float angle;
float rangle=2.0;
float xangle;
float yangle;


- (void)update:(float)dt
{

    if ([str isEqualToString:@"right"])
    {
        x=0;    y=1;  z=0;              //ROTATE OBJECT IN Y-AXIS(Y=1 & X=0)
        yAngle+=rAngle;                 //GET ANGLE OF OBJECT ROTATION IN Y-AXIS (ANTI CLOCKWISE)
        angle +=rAngle;                 //INCREMENT ANGLE OF OBJECT ROTATION IN ANTICLOCLWISE
    }
    else if ([str isEqualToString:@"left"])
    {
        x=0;    y=1;  z=0;              //ROTATE OBJECT IN Y-AXIS(Y=1 & X=0)
        yAngle-=rAngle;                 //GET ANGLE OF OBJECT ROTATION IN Y-AXIS (CLOCLWISE)
        angle -= rAngle;                //INC ANGLE OF OBJECT ROTATION IN CLOCKWISE

    }
    else if ([str isEqualToString:@"bottom"])
    {
        x=1;    y=0;  z=0;              //ROTATE OBJECT IN X-AXIS(X=1 & Y=0)
        xAngle+=rAngle;                 //GET ANGLE OF OBJECT ROTATION IN X-AXIS (ANTI CLOCKWISE)
        angle += rAngle;                //INC ANGLE OF OBJECT ROTATION

    }
    else if ([str isEqualToString:@"top"])
    {
        x=1;    y=0;  z=0 ;              //ROTATE OBJECT IN Y-AXIS(X=1 & Y=0)
        xAngle-=rAngle;                 //GET ANGLE OF OBJECT ROTATION IN X-AXIS (CLOCLWISE)
        angle -= rAngle;                //INC ANGLE OF OBJECT ROTATION


    }

    else
    {
        angle +=rAngle;
    }
//    teapotNode_.rotationAxis = CC3VectorMake(x, y, z);
//    teapotNode_.rotationAngle = angle;
    teapotNode_.rotation = CC3VectorMake(xAngle, yAngle, 0);

}
```